# Navigation bar overlaps with bottom bar icons

Tags: android

I am Android developer and dealing with Android Nougat (7.0) source code. I experienced kind of strange problem in Snapchat app. In the app, bottom bar icons overlap with the android navigation bar, so I can't use bottom bar icons in the app. I found this issue from different resources as well so I am confused whether this problem is in the app side or in the code base. Does anyone have any idea what can cause this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your xml code

Comment: You have used translucent flag in navigation bar remove it

Answer (score 2):

Add this line in your styles.xml file

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
```